# Child component event emitter not fired in parent

Tags: angular, emit

I have problem with output emitter not working in parent component. It is working inside child component but not triggerred in parent. It should be correct configuration. Why is it not firing inside parent component?I have problem with output emitter not working in parent component. It is working inside child component but not triggerred in parent. It should be correct configuration. Why is it not firing inside parent component?

Child Template:

```
   
<div>
     <ngx-table         
        #table        
        [id]="id"
        [configuration]="configuration"
        [data]="data"
        [columns]="columns"
        [noResultsTemplate]="noResultsTemplate">
      </ngx-table>
        <button (click)="onUpdateClick()"> Update </button>
        <button (click)="onDeleteClick()"> Delete </button>
</div>
```

Child controller

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, ViewChild, Output, EventEmitter, TemplateRef } from '@angular/core';
    import { DefaultConfig, Config, Columns, APIDefinition, API } from 'ngx-easy-table';
    import { CallType } from '../../models/call';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-datatable',
  templateUrl: './datatable.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./datatable.component.scss']
})
export class DatatableComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('table', { static: true }) table: APIDefinition;
  @ViewChild('actionTable', { static: true }) actionTable: TemplateRef<any>;

  @Output() updateButtonClick = new EventEmitter<>();
  @Output() deleteButtonClick = new EventEmitter<>();
  @Input() columns: Columns[];
  @Input() data: any;
  @Input() id: any;
  public configuration: Config;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.configuration = { ...DefaultConfig };
    this.configuration.searchEnabled = false;
    this.configuration.rows = 3;
    this.columns = [...this.columns, {key: 'action', title: 'Action', cellTemplate: this.actionTable, width: '15%'}];

  }


  onChange(name: string): void {
    this.table.apiEvent({
      type: API.onGlobalSearch, value: name,
    });
  }

  onUpdateClick() {
    console.log();
    this.updateButtonClick.emit();
  }

  onDeleteClick() {
    this.deleteButtonClick.emit();
  }

}
```

Parent Template

```
<app-datatable
  [id]="'idMytable'"
  [data]="data" [columns]="columns">
  (updateButtonClick)="openEditCallTypeModal()"
  (deleteButtonClick)="openDeleteCallTypeModal()">
</app-datatable>
```

Parent Controller

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { APIDefinition, Config, Columns, DefaultConfig, API } from 'ngx-easy-table';
import { BsModalRef, BsModalService } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';
import { SettingService } from '../../setting.service';
import { CallType } from 'src/app/shared/models/call';
import { CallTypeModalComponent } from './edit-call-type/call-type-modal.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-call-type-table',
  templateUrl: './call-type-table.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./call-type-table.component.scss']
})
export class CallTypeTableComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() callTypes: CallerType[];

  columns = [
    { key: 'id', title: 'Id', width: '10%'},
    { key: 'nameEN', title: 'English', width: '25%'  }
  ];

  bsModalRef: BsModalRef;

  constructor(private modalService: BsModalService, private settingService: SettingService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }


  openDeleteCallTypeModal() {//not firing code
    console.log('clicked');
  }

  openEditCallTypeModal(){
       // here is not calling
    console.log("work"); 
  }
}
```

Comment: Possibly unrelated, but provide a type to the `EventEmitter<>`. Replace it with `EventEmitter<any>`.

Answer (score 0):

You're binding different handlers to same emitter (`updateButtonClick`) twice in the parent template.

```html
<!-- wrong -->
<app-datatable
  [id]="'idMytable'"
  [data]="data" [columns]="columns"> /// here is something wrong
  (updateButtonClick)="openEditCallTypeModal()"
  (updateButtonClick)="openDeleteCallTypeModal()">
</app-datatable>
```

should be

```html
<app-datatable
  [id]="'idMytable'"
  [data]="data" [columns]="columns"
  (updateButtonClick)="openEditCallTypeModal()"
  (deleteButtonClick)="openDeleteCallTypeModal()">
</app-datatable>
```

Comment: @Sras: It works here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-7ab9ce

Comment: Child Component is located inside SharedModule. while Parent is in SettingModule. I already import SharedModule inside SettingModule. Am I missing something here? THey are not direct parent child component